# What is the equivalent to the MySQL DELIMITER in Azure?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

What is the equivalent to the MySQL `DELIMITER` statement using Azure?

For example, in MySQL you can do this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER foo 
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (some condition) THEN
    SELECT * FROM table2;
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually from the [Azure MySQL doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/), you could know it's still MySQL Server engine and support `The MySQL Command-Line Client` to manage MySQL. So the MySQL statement is also applicable for Azure MySQL.

I test with CMD to connect Azure MySQL.

1.Check the default properties with `status`. You could find the `Using delimiter` is `;` now.

[image]

2.Use `DELIMITER //` to change the delimiter. Then check the status.

[image]

So `DELIMITER` does apply to Azure MySQL.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems like a terrible question in hindsight xD.  I'm not actually using Azure myself, but the use of `DELIMITER` came up in a question I was trying to answer and I couldn't easily find something online.